# Laravel 5.* root path in subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have base domain routes and subdomain routes. For example if I request `subdomain.example.com/test` it will return me right answer. But if I want to request `subdomain.example.com` it will execute code from root domain.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    // Main 
});

Route::get('/path', function() {
    // .. 
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.example.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function() {
        // How to request this part?
    });

     Route::get('/test', function() {
        // Works
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the order in which they're defined?

Comment: @ceejayoz Hm.. I haven't thought about it, but yes, it works! Thanks!

Comment: Neat, adding that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the order will help - Laravel keeps the routes in order, and checks them one-by-one, so by moving the subdomain's routes above the main routes they'll get found first and used, with the global routes as fallbacks for other domains.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain.example.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function() {
        // How to request this part?
    });

     Route::get('/test', function() {
        // Works
    });
}

Route::get('/', function() {
    // Main 
});

Route::get('/path', function() {
    // .. 
});
```